# Append styles in iframe with Javascript (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, styles

Within the admin area of a website builder, I want the user to visually see the style changes before saving the updates.

I iframe the users website in so styles can be adjusted visually (over the top, so to speak). I have access and own both the admin site although they are different codebases and a users site can use a custom domain name, which I believe could be an issue.

I've set up `Content-Security-Policy` to allow the admin area to pull in the iframe and that works as expected. But I can't append a temporary `<style>` tag to the head.

Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="designer">
        <div class="designer-sidebar">
        <!-- style options -->
        </div>

        <div class="designer-content">
            <iframe id="the-iframe" class="designer-frame" src="http://thechildsite.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                updating: false,
                device: 'desktop'
            }
        },
        ready () {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('the-iframe')
            var style = document.createElement('style')
            style.textContent =
                'body {' +
                '  background-color: lime;' +
                '  color: pink;' +
                '}'
            ;
            iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collegue helped me find a solution based on `postMessage`. More details here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

In the Vue.js app:

```
<div class="designer-content">
    <iframe ref="iframeContent" class="designer-frame" :src="liveSite" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" @load="iframeStyles">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>

methods: {
    iframeStyles() {
        this.frame = this.$refs.iframeContent.contentWindow;

        const style =
            '.layout__wrapper {background:' + this.background + ';} ' +
            'body {color:' + this.text + ';} '
        this.frame.postMessage(style, '*');
    }
}
```

In the site you want to iframe in:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (e.origin === 'https://app.theparentapp.com') {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = e.data;
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Just replicated your code, for me the `var iframe` is always null?

Switching the `ready()` to `mounted()` populates `var iframe` with the iframe.

The style tag wasn't getting populated either so I tried this:

```
var css = document.createElement('style');
css.type = 'text/css';

var styles = 'body {' +
    '  background-color: lime;' +
    '  color: pink;' +
'}';

css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));

iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(css);
```

It still doesn't actually append the style to the iframe (could be a permissions thing on my part?), but console logging out the `css` looks a bit more like it should? Hope this is at least a bit helpful!

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm certainly not getting any errors now. But I think there must be a permissions issue with cross domains. I need to investigate further :/

Comment: Apologies.. Just realised this morning that you're not using vue.js 2! My advice is probably mostly useless! Hope you managed to resolve it.

Comment: No problem. It is Vue.js 2 - I was defaulting to old code by habit. I think your suggestion works, but I have a feeling permissions are getting in the way.